# Can we get jacoco report when test run fails

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco

Can we get jacoco report when test run fails?

1. During execution of the tests if test gets failed then if we can able to proceed and create report?
2. If any way to create .exec file when we do manual execution

Thanks,